# How to establish a connection to a database using TCP?

Tags: database, tcp

I'm trying to establish TCP connection with `PostgreSQL 9.1 server` via `Microsoft telnet`. but When the connection has been establishe I received

```
Jconnector 3.6 1 ♥
```

What does it mean? Is it opssible at all to establish such connection manually to communicate the database via TCP?

Comment: Do you know the Postgres network protocol? If not you can't expect to make sense out of what the server tells you. What did you expect to receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a TCP connection to a port is opened, what is listening on the Port sometimes announces itself: in this case, what is listening is Jconnector 3.6.1. The heart-shape is some binary data.

TCP connections tend to be only used by program code, as 'conversations' at that level quite often involve binary data. I don't know what Postgres does, but if you get it to run a select and return the data it will very likely be all binary and quire unreadable by a human.

If you search for what the wire-protocol is for Postgres, you may be able to make it do something via a telnet session, but expect you'd have a lot of difficulty.